# Topbar covering webpage header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website and want a navigation bar that stays at the top of the screen. I can do this fine but when I scroll to top it goes above header. How do I get it to stop scrolling with the user before the top of the page? I have watched countless tutorials but none seem to work. I think I need JavaScript to unstick the bar at a certain height, but unsure how. Also how do I restick it when the user scrolls back down?

Comment: For future reference, you should include the code that you have tried so far and which is not working when you ask a question, see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need JavaScript to handle this. It is not too complicated, but you will basically need to add an event handler for the [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) event on the `window`, and inside the handler you can check the `scrollTop` of the `window` to see how much has been scrolled. When it has been scrolled "enough" (usually the height of your header) you can then switch the position of the header to fixed.

You can see a demo about it on the excellent [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/), and there are many tutorials and plugins that can help with this.

Comment: Ok I got it to work if anyone wants code I can post it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as danwellman said, you need js.
I have a small code I used in my webpage.

```
// Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
    offset: 51
});
```

You need a file like "scrolling-nav.js" or anything you prefer. And in your html, don't forget to call it.

```
// In the end or in the beggining you call your js file
<script src="...(filepath)/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
```

There are many more cool possible snippets you can find. This is really to keep the navbar fixed after the offset of '51'. You can also add the smoothed movement to the webpage section after selecting a menu button.. If you have a onepage website, for example. This would also be js.

Good luck. :)